# How to style prismjs copy to clipboard button?

Tags: css, ghost-blog, prismjs

I want to copy the exact code block design designed by Ghost using [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/index.html).

Here is the link - https://ghost.org/tutorials/code-snippets-in-ghost/

The end result must look like the below screenshot.

[image]

What I tried looks like this.

[image]

Link for the settings I enabled for the code block formatting in prismjs.

https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism-okaidia&languages=css+clike+javascript+css-extras&plugins=autolinker+custom-class+show-language+inline-color+autoloader+toolbar+copy-to-clipboard+match-braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

If you want exactly the same styles as on the page

https://ghost.org/tutorials/code-snippets-in-ghost/

here is a instruction to get their theme file, download and name it `prism.css`

1. Open the 'Sources' tab in the `DevTools`
2. Find and click on the `/tutorials/assets/built/components/syntax-highlighting.css` file
3. Right click on a tab with content of `syntax-highlighting.css`
4. Save as... `prism.css`

**Snippet with all rules including copy button:**

*(the button is not shown in the snippet when using prism.js from CDN)*

Similarity is achieved by adding css rules, but there is no animation.
[image]

```css
/**
 * MIT License
 * Copyright (c) 2018 Sarah Drasner
 * Sarah Drasner's[@sdras] Night Owl
 * Ported by Sara vieria [@SaraVieira]
 * Added by Souvik Mandal [@SimpleIndian]
 */

 code[class*="language-"],
 pre[class*="language-"] {
     font-family: var(--font-mono);
     font-size: inherit;
     hyphens: none;
     line-height: 1.6;
     color: #d6deeb;
     text-align: left;
     word-break: normal;
     word-wrap: normal;
     tab-size: 4;
     tab-size: 4;
     tab-size: 4;
     white-space: pre;
     word-spacing: normal;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
 }
 
 pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
 pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
 code[class*="language-"]::selection,
 code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
     text-shadow: none;
     background: rgb(29 59 83 / 99%);
 }
 
 pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
 pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
 code[class*="language-"]::selection,
 code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
     text-shadow: none;
     background: rgb(29 59 83 / 99%);
 }
 
 @media print {
     code[class*="language-"],
     pre[class*="language-"] {
         text-shadow: none;
     }
 }
 
 /* Code blocks */
 pre[class*="language-"] {
     padding: 25px;
     margin-top: 3.2vmin;
     overflow: auto;
 }
 
 :not(pre) > code[class*="language-"],
 pre[class*="language-"] {
     color: white;
     background: #011627;
 }
 
 :not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
     padding: 0.1em;
     white-space: normal;
     border-radius: 0.3em;
 }
 
 .token.comment,
 .token.prolog,
 .token.cdata {
     font-style: italic;
     color: rgb(99 119 119);
 }
 
 .token.punctuation {
     color: rgb(199 146 234);
 }
 
 .namespace {
     color: rgb(178 204 214);
 }
 
 .token.deleted {
     font-style: italic;
     color: rgb(239 83 80 / 56%);
 }
 
 .token.symbol,
 .token.property {
     color: rgb(128 203 196);
 }
 
 .token.tag,
 .token.operator,
 .token.keyword {
     color: rgb(127 219 202);
 }
 
 .token.boolean {
     color: rgb(255 88 116);
 }
 
 .token.number {
     color: rgb(247 140 108);
 }
 
 .token.constant,
 .token.function,
 .token.builtin,
 .token.char {
     color: rgb(130 170 255);
 }
 
 .token.selector,
 .token.doctype {
     font-style: italic;
     color: rgb(199 146 234);
 }
 
 .token.attr-name,
 .token.inserted {
     font-style: italic;
     color: rgb(173 219 103);
 }
 
 .token.string,
 .token.url,
 .token.entity,
 .language-css .token.string,
 .style .token.string {
     color: rgb(173 219 103);
 }
 
 .token.class-name,
 .token.atrule,
 .token.attr-value {
     color: rgb(255 203 139);
 }
 
 .token.regex,
 .token.important,
 .token.variable {
     color: rgb(214 222 235);
 }
 
 .token.important,
 .token.bold {
     font-weight: 700;
 }
 
 .token.italic {
     font-style: italic;
 }
 
 /* Custom styles for theme */
 .code-wrapper {
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     border-radius: 8px;
 }
 
 .code-wrapper > pre[class*="language-"] {
     margin-top: 0;
 }


div.code-toolbar{
    position:relative
}
div.code-toolbar>.toolbar{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    top:.3em;
    right:.2em;
    transition:opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity:1
}

div.code-toolbar>.toolbar>.toolbar-item{
    display:inline-block
}
div.code-toolbar>.toolbar>.toolbar-item>a{
    cursor:pointer
}

/* feature styles for buttons */

/* icon copy */
div.code-toolbar>.toolbar>.toolbar-item>button > span
{
    color: transparent;
    background-color:#e6caa8;
    mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M7 6V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-3v3c0 .552-.45 1-1.007 1H4.007A1.001 1.001 0 0 1 3 21l.003-14c0-.552.45-1 1.007-1H7zM5.003 8L5 20h10V8H5.003zM9 6h8v10h2V4H9v2z' fill='currentColor'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    mask-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    mask-position: center right;
}

/* hide icon copy */
div.code-toolbar>.toolbar>.toolbar-item>button[data-copy-state=copy-success] > span ,
div.code-toolbar>.toolbar>.toolbar-item>button[data-copy-state=copy-success]:hover > span
{
    mask-image: none;
    color: #e6caa8;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/* color of "Copied!" */
.copy-to-clipboard-button[data-copy-state~=copy-success] span {
    color: #e6caa8;
}

/* text copy is hidden */
.copy-to-clipboard-button[data-copy-state=copy] span {
    color: transparent;
}

/* default item color */
div.code-toolbar>.toolbar>.toolbar-item {
   color: #e6caa8; 
}

/* remove toolbar items decoration*/
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar > .toolbar-item > a, 
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar > .toolbar-item > button, 
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar > .toolbar-item > span {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/prism.min.js" integrity="sha512-7Z9J3l1+EYfeaPKcGXu3MS/7T+w19WtKQY/n+xzmw4hZhJ9tyYmcUS+4QqAlzhicE5LAfMQSF3iFTK9bQdTxXg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<pre>
<code class="language-css">
    .token.boolean,
    .token.number,
    .token.function {
            color: #f08d49;
    }
</code>
</pre>
```

**Solution 2**:

The most interesting part of the code came from researching the sources on ghost.org (**button event**: */tutorials/src/js/post/code-copy.js*) and the sources of the buttons on [github](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/blob/master/plugins/copy-to-clipboard/prism-copy-to-clipboard.js), however, in order to make it work, I had to make a symbiosis of two scripts
because it doesn't work as it should ( functions `copyTextToClipboard`, `fallbackCopyTextToClipboard` from github converted to async).

**Now copy button looks and works like the original:**

[image]

```js
function initCodeCopy() {
    const codeBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('code[class*="language-"]');
    codeBlocks.forEach((block) => {
      const lang = parseLanguage(block);
      const referenceEl = block.parentElement;
      const parent = block.parentElement.parentElement;
      
      const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      wrapper.className = 'code-wrapper';
      parent.insertBefore(wrapper, referenceEl);
      wrapper.append(block.parentElement);

      const copyBtn = document.createElement('button');
      copyBtn.setAttribute('class', 'copy-button');
      copyBtn.setAttribute('data-lang', lang);
      copyBtn.innerHTML = `${lang} <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/><path d="M7 6V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-3v3c0 .552-.45 1-1.007 1H4.007A1.001 1.001 0 0 1 3 21l.003-14c0-.552.45-1 1.007-1H7zM5.003 8L5 20h10V8H5.003zM9 6h8v10h2V4H9v2z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>`;

      wrapper.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', copyBtn);
    });

    function parseLanguage(block) {
      const className = block.className;
      if (className.startsWith('language')) {
        const [prefix, lang] = className.split('-');
        return lang;
      }
    }

        async function fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
                textArea.value = copyInfo.getText();
                // Avoid scrolling to bottom
                textArea.style.top = '0';
                textArea.style.left = '0';
                textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
                document.body.appendChild(textArea);
                textArea.focus();
                textArea.select();
                try {
                    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        if (successful) {
                            resolve('success')
                        } else {
                            reject('error')
                        }
                    }, 1);
                } catch (err) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        reject(err)
                    }, 1);
                } finally {
                    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
                }
            })  
        }
    
        async function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (navigator.clipboard) {
                    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(
                        resolve(), function () {
                        // try the fallback in case `writeText` didn't work
                        fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text).then(
                            () => resolve(),
                            () => reject()
                        )
                    });
                } else {
                    fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text).then(
                        () => resolve(),
                        () => reject()
                    )
                }
            })
        }

    function copy(e) {
        const btn = e.currentTarget;
        const lang = btn.dataset.lang;
        const text = e.currentTarget.previousSibling.children[0].textContent;
        copyTextToClipboard(text)
            .then(
            () => {
                btn.innerHTML = `copied! <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/><path d="M7 6V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-3v3c0 .552-.45 1-1.007 1H4.007A1.001 1.001 0 0 1 3 21l.003-14c0-.552.45-1 1.007-1H7zm2 0h8v10h2V4H9v2z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>`;
                btn.setAttribute('style', 'opacity: 1');
                
            },
            () => alert('failed to copy'),
        );

        setTimeout(() => {
            btn.removeAttribute('style');
            btn.innerHTML = `${lang} <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/><path d="M7 6V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-3v3c0 .552-.45 1-1.007 1H4.007A1.001 1.001 0 0 1 3 21l.003-14c0-.552.45-1 1.007-1H7zM5.003 8L5 20h10V8H5.003zM9 6h8v10h2V4H9v2z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>`;
        }, 3000);
    }

    const copyButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-button');

    copyButtons.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', copy);
    });
    }
    initCodeCopy()
```

```css
/**
 * MIT License
 * Copyright (c) 2018 Sarah Drasner
 * Sarah Drasner's[@sdras] Night Owl
 * Ported by Sara vieria [@SaraVieira]
 * Added by Souvik Mandal [@SimpleIndian]
 */
* {
  margin:0; /* make bottom corners round */
}

code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
    font-family: var(--font-mono);
    font-size: inherit;
    hyphens: none;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #d6deeb;
    text-align: left;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    tab-size: 4;
    tab-size: 4;
    tab-size: 4;
    white-space: pre;
    word-spacing: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
}

pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
code[class*="language-"]::selection,
code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: rgb(29 59 83 / 99%);
}

pre[class*="language-"]::selection,
pre[class*="language-"] ::selection,
code[class*="language-"]::selection,
code[class*="language-"] ::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: rgb(29 59 83 / 99%);
}

@media print {
    code[class*="language-"],
    pre[class*="language-"] {
        text-shadow: none;
    }
}

/* Code blocks */
pre[class*="language-"] {
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 3.2vmin;
    overflow: auto;
}

:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
    color: white;
    background: #011627;
}

:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
    padding: 0.1em;
    white-space: normal;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
}

.token.comment,
.token.prolog,
.token.cdata {
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgb(99 119 119);
}

.token.punctuation {
    color: rgb(199 146 234);
}

.namespace {
    color: rgb(178 204 214);
}

.token.deleted {
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgb(239 83 80 / 56%);
}

.token.symbol,
.token.property {
    color: rgb(128 203 196);
}

.token.tag,
.token.operator,
.token.keyword {
    color: rgb(127 219 202);
}

.token.boolean {
    color: rgb(255 88 116);
}

.token.number {
    color: rgb(247 140 108);
}

.token.constant,
.token.function,
.token.builtin,
.token.char {
    color: rgb(130 170 255);
}

.token.selector,
.token.doctype {
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgb(199 146 234);
}

.token.attr-name,
.token.inserted {
    font-style: italic;
    color: rgb(173 219 103);
}

.token.string,
.token.url,
.token.entity,
.language-css .token.string,
.style .token.string {
    color: rgb(173 219 103);
}

.token.class-name,
.token.atrule,
.token.attr-value {
    color: rgb(255 203 139);
}

.token.regex,
.token.important,
.token.variable {
    color: rgb(214 222 235);
}

.token.important,
.token.bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.token.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Custom styles for theme */
.code-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.code-wrapper > pre[class*="language-"] {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.copy-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(230 202 168);
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: #011627;
    border: none;
}

.copy-button svg {
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: 0.25em;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.copy-button:hover svg {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/prism.min.js" integrity="sha512-7Z9J3l1+EYfeaPKcGXu3MS/7T+w19WtKQY/n+xzmw4hZhJ9tyYmcUS+4QqAlzhicE5LAfMQSF3iFTK9bQdTxXg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<pre class="language-css"><code class="language-css">.token.boolean,
    .token.number,
    .token.function {
            color: #f08d49;
    }
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that when I do this, it just shows a yellow box, instead of an icon?

Comment: @HamzaSayyid, please put you code in a sandbox and share the link